# Drupal 7 - Run rule on every user triggered by cron

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

Is it possible to run a rule on every user triggered when the cron runs.

I need to check every users subscription stutus (commerce subscription module) and if the subscription has expired downgrade their role.

I was hoping the module had this feature but apparently not.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, make your rule as normal, write a small custom module and implement [`hook_cron()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to run `rules_invoke_event()`.

```
function MYMODULE_cron() {
  rules_invoke_event('rule_name', $arg1, $arg2, $argN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Outdated answer. It's now possible to select "Cron maintenance tasks" when selecting what triggers the rule.